# SpringBOOT : Saving object in API

Tags: spring-boot, postman, h2

Not able to save the JSON object passing through postman.
Here are the files:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hardwares")
public class HardwaresList {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "hardwareId")
    private int hardwareId;

    @Column(name = "hardwareName")
    private String hardwareName;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.id + " " + this.hardwareName;
    }
}
```

HardwareListService

```
package com.hardware.procurement.hardware;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class HardwareListService {

    @Autowired
    private HardwareListRepo hardwareListRepo;

    public void saveOrUpdateHardware(HardwaresList list){
        hardwareListRepo.save(list);
    }
```

HardwareRepo

```
package com.hardware.procurement.hardware;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface HardwareListRepo extends CrudRepository<HardwaresList, Long> {

}
```

HardwareController

```
package com.hardware.procurement.hardware;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/procurement")
public class HardwareListController {

    @Autowired
    private HardwareListService hardwareListService;

    @PostMapping("/hardwares")
    public void saveHardware(@RequestBody HardwaresList hardwaresList){
        hardwareListService.saveOrUpdateHardware(hardwaresList);
    }
```

applicationProperties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:D:/h2-data
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hardware</groupId>
    <artifactId>procurement</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>procurement</name>
    <description>API for hardware procurement</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>
                        -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
                    </jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And this is how I am sending body from the postman but I am getting data integrity violation. Even though I am sending unique values. Please help me out with this.
[image]

```
    {"timestamp":"2021-09-16T22:35:00.858+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","trace":"org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [\"PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.HARDWARES(HARDWAREID) [0, NULL]\"; SQL statement:insert into hardwares (hardwarename, hardwareid) values (?, ?) [23505-200]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:276)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.save(Unknown Source)
at com.hardware.procurement.hardware.HardwareListService.saveOrUpdateHardware(HardwareListService.java:16)
at com.hardware.procurement.hardware.HardwareListController.saveHardware(HardwareListController.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3298)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3825)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3212)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2380)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:448)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)
... 66 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: \"PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.HARDWARES(HARDWAREID) [0, NULL]\"; SQL statement:
insert into hardwares (hardwarename, hardwareid) values (?, ?) [23505-200]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:459)
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVPrimaryIndex.add(MVPrimaryIndex.java:127)
at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.addRow(MVTable.java:531)
at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:195)
at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:151)
at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:198)
at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:191)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:152)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
... 86 more
","message":"could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [\"PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.HARDWARES(HARDWAREID) [0, NULL]\"; SQL statement:
insert into hardwares (hardwarename, hardwareid) values (?, ?) [23505-200]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement","path":"/procurement/hardwares"}
```

Comment: can you add the full stack trace error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.HARDWARES(HARDWAREID) [0, NULL]
```

Your entity seems invalid. The entity doesn't have `getters` or `setters` for them and JPA would have no idea how to set them. See the error that says hardware ID is 0 though you explicitly passed '1'. Try generating the getters and setters for your entity.

Answer (score 0):

You are using GenerationType.IDENTITY which reads in the documentation as “Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using a database identity column.” This means that unless your database supports this (it seems it does not) you might need to change the generation type. I would suggest you to consider using SEQUENCE instead. Take a look at this article —> https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers.

Comment: Hi, I tried removing that line and inserting data through postman. I am still getting the same exception.

Comment: If you are using SEQUENCE now you need to create the sequence in the database so that the IDs are generated.

Comment: Refer to https://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/generatedvalue-strategy-generationtype-sequence-hibernate.